# cannot edit ion-input value with [(ngModel)]

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular10

so I have a problem with my app. I have an edit page for editing recipes however I cannot edit the ion-input for the Ingredients and Steps (image attached)
[Screenshot for the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVX4d.png)

This is the video that I recorded to get a better understanding of the problem -> [see video here](https://www.loom.com/share/ad49a819a16c4378a729c24aa451d6d8)

the ion-input data comes from an array. Here's my code for the ingredients input

```jsx
<ion-col size="12" size-lg="4" offset-lg="0" size-md="8" offset-md="2" size-sm="12" class="formCol formCol__midCol">
  <ion-text color="primary">
    <h3>Ingredients</h3>
  </ion-text>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item lines="none">
      <ion-label>
        Tell people what ingredients should be prepared? *
      </ion-label>
    </ion-item>
    <ng-container *ngFor="
                  let ingredient of ingredients;
                  let i = index;
                  let last = last;
                  let start = first
                ">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Add ingredient e.x. 1.5 tbsp olive oil" [(ngModel)]="recipe.ingredients[i]" name="ingredient_{{ i }}" required #ingredient="ngModel"></ion-input>
        <ion-icon style="font-size: 16px" name="close-circle-outline" (click)="deleteInputItem('ingredient', i)"></ion-icon>
      </ion-item>

      <form-field-error [control]="ingredient"></form-field-error>
    </ng-container>
  </ion-list>
  <ion-button (click)="addIngredient()" color="#ff6260" fill="clear">
    <ion-icon name="add-circle" slot="start" color="#ff6260"></ion-icon>
    Add more ingredient
  </ion-button>
</ion-col>
```

this is where I assign value for ingredients:

```ts
this.ingredients = this.recipe.ingredients;
```

and this is what's the array looks like:

```ts
["1 ½ pounds medium to large Brussessls sprouts, trimmed (16-18)", "1tbsps"]
```

Answer (score 0):

In ts for use array with object instead of array

Try this code.

`htmlcode`

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of ingredients; let i =index">
        <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Add ingredient e.x. 1.5 tbsp olive oil" [(ngModel)]="item.item"
            name="ingredient_{{i}}" required #ingredient="ngModel"></ion-input>
        <ion-icon style="font-size: 16px" name="close-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
```

`tsCode`

```
public ingredients = [{
    item: '1 ½ pounds medium to large Bsrusssessls sprouts, trimmed (16-18)'
  }, {
    item: '1tbsps'
  }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [(ngModel)]="ingredients" instead of [(ngModel)]="recipe.ingredients[i]"

```
 <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Add ingredient e.x. 1.5 tbsp olive oil" [(ngModel)]="ingredient" name="ingredient_{{ i }}" required #ingredient="ngModel"></ion-input>
```

Comment: hi I tried your suggestion but it is still have the issue, any advise?

Comment: you have to use the array of objects instead of array of strings. Make the ingredients an array of objects something like ingredients = [{name: 'some ingredient'}, {name: 'second ingredient'}]. One easy solution to convert your strings array to objects one is to use a pipe.